# Will using arguments - max_length, truncate, and padding in tranformers pipeline affect the output?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, sentiment-analysis

Hello so I was checking sentiment of a text using transformers pretrained model ,but doing so gave me error

> RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (1954) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1

I went through few post which suggested that setting `max_length` as 512 will sort the error.
It did resolve the error, but I want to know how it affects the quality of output. Does it truncate my text? For example, if the length of my text is 1195 will it process till 512, something like text[:512]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It means the sentiment will be based on the first 512 *tokens*, and any tokens after that will not influence the result.

Note that this is tokens, not characters. If `text` was your raw string, and if we assume that on average each token is 2.5 characters, then truncating at 512 tokens would be the same as `text[:1280]`.

(The characters per token can vary a lot based on the model, the tokenizer, the language, the domain, but mainly how unusual the string is compared to the text used to train the tokenizer.)

By the way, according to https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/pad_truncation if you don't specify `truncation` then no truncation is applied; and if you do, but don't specify `max_length` then it will default to the maximum supported by the model. So setting `max_length` and not changing anything else shouldn't have fixed it. (I've not tested anything, or read the code, that is just based on my understanding of the documentation.)

Comment: Based on my understanding of the  above explanation , my current output is not correct, since what I wanted is to analyze the sentiments of news articles and for that I was using transformers pipeline with model distilebert ,but if it only considers first 512 tokens then the the output is not entirely correct .Is there any way to bypass this , could you please share your input on this ?

Comment: @help_180399 That ("How to use more context than the model is trained for") is a whole separate question. Half the research since the original transformer paper has been on how to get more context while avoid the O(N^2) scaling. But if changing model is not an option, splitting your long sentence into chunks, analyzing each chunk, then averaging the results is another way.

Comment: _"if it only considers first 512 tokens then the the output is not entirely correct ..."_

The result will not be "entirely correct" anyway. The models don't have perfect comprehension, and when it comes to judging sentiment of a long sentence, even human linguists will disagree. So the question is will analyzing more than 512 tokens give a worthwhile improvement in accuracy.